# How to associate comments to users on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, post, comments

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
    $this->validate(request(), ['body' => 'required|min:2']);

    $post->addComment(request('body'));

    return back();
}
```

this is my code

I am having this error 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `post_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ewrtyuttrew, 1, 2018-02-15 15:44:17, 2018-02-15 15:44:17))

Comment: The right way is foing that by defining the relationship in models. Second answer is the right one. the first one is not the Laravel solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a user who created the comment manually. For example:

```
public function addComment(string $body)
{
    $this->comments()->create(['body' => $body, 'user_id' => auth()->id()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **User** model you can define the relationship as:

```
public function comments() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

So, if the user it's the logged user, then you can retrieve it with the **Auth** facade:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$user->comments()->save(new Comment(request('body'));
```

Note that you must set the "fillable" fields on the **Comment** model in order to allow the dynamic creation.

Answer (score 0):

Field 'user_id'

Open phpmyadmin and open comments table then after

Field 'user_id' => auto increment and primary key add

Try this I solve this type issues, thanks